# How to scroll away the uiview and have a continuous ui collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a problem with the uiview and a ui collection view in a fixed position. Is there a way to scroll the ui view upwards and have an infinite ui collection view under with content? I want the whole view to be uicollection. Is there something I have to do with my constraints?

--uiview

----uiview << sorta like a header for the page which can be scrolled up and out of the way. But once at the top, they will see it again.

----uicollection view <<< whole view should push up a continuous ui collection view

Currently the uiview and uicollection view are on the same layer.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the UICollectionViewController with UINavigationController as its parent. You can hide navigation controller as you want and take whole screen for UICollectionview.

Comment: Possible to see a screenshot?

Comment: @Mikael I'm shooting for a similar effect as this one from pintrest with the uiview as the name/logo section and then a ui collection view at the bottom, but as you scroll, the top section goes away, independent from the navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to add a header to your UICollection views. There are MANY tutorials that can help you. This one here can get you started: http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/